# Importing with EGit clones repository but doesn't let me import project

Tags: eclipse, git, github, clone, egit

I just started my third repository on Github. I initialized the repository on the website with a README file and tried importing it into Eclipse with Egit. Like my other projects from Github, the import dialog worked fine and the repository was cloned. In my file explorer, I can see the folder Egit created, as well as the .git folder and the README from the repository.

However, when I get to the point where Eclipse wants me to choose a wizard for project import, everything stops working. I can't import an existing project, because none exists yet. If I try to import it as a general project, it doesn't let me go further because it claims:

> /path/to/my/folder overlaps the location of another project: 'gnu_magic'

This is indeed the name of the project I'm trying to import, but as I just imported it for the first time that shouldn't be a problem.

If I use the new project wizard, it doesn't let me use the same folder name as the project, claiming that the folder is not empty (which is true, but strange when I'm using the wizard to create an entirely new project). If I give the folder another name, it creates a project but the project isn't connected to the repository - I have no way of committing my changes back to Github.

Deleting the gnu_magic folder and starting all over again brings the same results.

Is there a way to remove the metadata over that specific project from Eclipse's configuration? I don't want to lose my other projects but I would like to work with Egit on that project.

Another interesting fact: If I clone the repository manually and then try to import it into Eclipse, as a project from my file system, it doesn't let me becasue the source is in the heirarchy of the destination.

Or am I missing the point here completely? I'm just surprised that I was able to clone the other repositories without any problems. Working with them over the past few days has been quite easy.

Comment: I think you lost a part of your

Comment: The problem is with your file system layout and eclipse projects.  Start a new workspace.

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without starting a new workspace? I've got a few projects and would hate to have to clone them all again. Plus, I've got my workbenches and plugins set up just the way I like them.

Comment: @DanielLee You don't have to clone them again. Just move them to your new workspace location and import them and then use Team -> Share Project to connect the Git repo again.

Comment: Using "New Project" and using the existing folder name works here, both for a normal project and a Java project. Are you using an older Eclipse version?

Comment: Are you trying to import a cloned git repository as project? This is not recommended. Your projects should be in subfolders of the repository.

Comment: @ Ozan - I'm basically trying to import the cloned repository at all, but Eclipse isn't able to see it.

Comment: @robinst - Thanks for the tip. I'm using the newest version of Eclipse, Juno. In my workspace location I can see the folder that was created while cloning the git repository, but Eclipse doesn't see it, so I can't use Team -> Share Project on it :(

Comment: Don't clone repositories into your workspace directory, and don't use repositories as root folder of your project. EGit has a mechanism to enable projects from different repositories in one workspace: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Considerations_for_Git_Repositories_to_be_used_in_Eclipse

Comment: I see, I think there's some confusion here. I'm not using my workspace directory as the root of my repository, I'm trying to use the EGit wizard to import the cloned repository as a project.

Comment: I ended up pushing the content I wanted to Github as @robinst said I should. It got to Github and I can see it there, but when I restarted Eclipse it was no longer connected to the repository. Since I knew it was backed up, I deleted the project and tried to reimport it into my workspace. Same problem again.

Comment: So for Eclipse to recognize that there is a project, you only need to have a `.project` file. So copy that file from an existing Eclipse project into your new project and adjust the name to match the folder name of the new project. After this, it should be possible to import the project.

Comment: @robinst - I had to delete the .project file. I think the problem was that I'd accidentally added it to my repository, which confused Eclipse when I was importing. Nonetheless, deleting it from the repo and then importing again didn't help. I found the solution now though, see answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was a bit strange. Here's the steps to solve it:

1. Clone repository using EGit
2. Eclipse refuses to import project, claiming it already exists. Exit import dialog.
3. Create new project using existing code, using cloned repository
4. Share project with old repository

Now the project is once again connected to the repository. Be careful with this method because if something goes wrong you might commit over your old code. This solution works with Indigo and Juno.

Comment: Had to do some tweaking, but in general this method worked for me.  Instead of "Create new project", I Import->General->"Existing Projects into Workspace", etc.  The key as you found out is step 4, Sharing the project with the old repository.  What a pain in a$$!

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Eclipse 4.2 Indigo, and I've been struggling with these same problems for a while now.

If you have already cloned a repository on your machine somewhere, using EGit or whatever, you can:

1) Create a new Eclipse project.

2) *File -> Import -> General -> File System* Choose the cloned repository location. This will import everything, including the .git folder within the repository, into your Eclipse project in your workspace. For this it doesn't matter whether there's .project files anywhere in the imported files or not.

3) *Team -> Share Project -> Git* The EGit plugin should detect the .git folder within your project and suggest settings accordingly. You will have a new local repository location addded to EGit's repositories which will point to the .git folder under your project's directory.

Comment: Do you really have to create a new Eclipse project?  Couldn't you just go straight to the import?

Comment: Yes, you can do that and go straight to import.